# Can anyone tell me where I can read about this initialization list? Python 2

Tags: python

I found this code:

```
line1 = [1,2,3,4,5] # list1

line2 = [0 for index in range(len(line1))] #line2 has the same length as line1
```

I understand that line2 has the same length of line 1 but I can not find anything about second statement.
Somebody can explains how this works?

Comment: What do you not know about, range, list comps, for loops..?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I try to edit mi question. Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). How the docs explain it:

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of some operations applied to each member of another sequence or iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a certain condition.

My explanation:

Instead of creating a list by a for loop and appending to a list previously initialized outside of the for loop, you can do the for loop inside of two square brackets and make a list that way. To better understand it, I will expand it for you:

```
line2 = []
for index in range(len(line1)):
    line2.append(0)
```